# High quality question marked as duplicate of newer mediocre question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, tag-badges

There's this 2009 question with nice answers, lots of views and nice answers:

- [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/962132/607407)

It is marked as a duplicate of this mediocre 2013 question with one (unaccepted) answer:

- [virtual function calls in constructor and destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18580779/607407)

It was marked using gold tag badge privileges, not normal voting process.

[image: image description]

Can someone please fix the duplicate relationship? The other question cannot currently be dupe closed because it would form a circle.

Comment: "I am starting to have serious issues with this privilege." Is this remark what your question is about or the dupe closed question?

Comment: No, that's just a side remark. Maybe I should've put it in comment.

Comment: FWIW imo the dupe close should indeed have been the other way around.

Comment: The gold badge owner that closed the older one had to re-open the newer one in order to do so. Basically, he reversed the closure. I have no clue why, though.

Comment: Sigh, I got lost in the rant and didn't understand what you actually want to happen. Do you simply want the duplicate relationship to be reversed?

Comment: I guess yes. and maybe that a voting system would have detected this instead of only one person deciding this relationship.

Comment: @CodyGray It must be easy for you to get lost, I said it clearly: "**This question is whether someone can please fix it.**". I voted to reopen on the older question, but I think this matter is clear enough to be resolved immediately, instead of laying in review queue for weeks.

Comment: What was unclear to me is precisely what you wanted "fixed". I hold a gold tag badge in C++, so I can fix it immediately, if I can get hammered down precisely what needs to be fixed. Assuming I don't lose interest first before I can figure it out.

Comment: Using a hammer is normal voting process. You can disagree wih it, but you don't need to write a rant to do so.

Comment: I closed the newer question as a dupe of the older one now.

Comment: I like the answer on the "mediocre" question better as well.  This has well defined behavior in C++, the panicky "it is dangerous" overtones are not terribly appropriate.  But whatever.  I suspect a merge would be more appropriate.

Comment: @HansPassant 'cos merging questions never leads to more meta questions... :)

Comment: @Hans Dietmar's answer isn't that bad, but I have to agree merging would be the appropriate action.

Comment: @Ninja What would it need to merge? Can it be done by a single mod?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yup - probably best if wait for more to chip in as to whether they feel it's warranted and which direction it should go in though... A merge will preserve all the answers on a *single* question - so someone needs to work out which is the better question as the other question will be left with no answers/comments/locked and just a stub back to the other one.

Comment: To jump in here, i was the one who reversed it in the first place, following this discussion in the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941163/polymorph-ability-of-virtual-function-called-in-destructor-of-base-class).  The feeling was that the highly upvoted answer was in fact misleading at best (and more likely wrong), and thus the later "mediocre" answer on the second question was in fact better, and should be where the dupe edge resolves to.  If there were a way to merge, I'd have done that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the duplicate relationship is now chronological.

Comment: Note that generally chronological order isn't *that* important. The end target should ideally be the "better" one. So in this case, the direction seems to be fairly clear. However, in *equally* good (by some metric the community wants to decide) posts, then it's just more *fair* the older post is the target.

Comment: You should note that it doesn't matter if dupes are chronological. As usual what actually counts is the quality of posts.

Comment: @Ninja You ninja'd me ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well if we wanna be nitpicky then we have to note that I did mention my subjective rating of both post's quality on the OP. I'm also kinda skeptical about the possibility that if I post nicer version of existing question then I can close old question as duplicate of mine.

Comment: @TomášZato sceptical in what sense? That the system allows it or whether you should do so?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy Some if both. What I'm trying to say is that I don't see anything wrong about that idea but it's quite unrealistic. If it became a standard, it would be abused so instead it's somewhere in the gray zone of "theoretically ok" and in reality asking better formed old question or even trying to get more details will usually lead in having new post closed.

Comment: The system won't prevent you from dupe hammering a question to your own - you've earned enough trust in that tag (and by the requirements of that - enough trust on the site overall) to make choices to maintain it as best you can/are willing to do so. However, you would run the potential risk of the community thinking you're doing it out of self-interest (ie: you want more votes on your question blah blah).

Comment: Don't forget though, that a question whether it be mod closed/dupe hammered/close voted normally - can always be reversed by the community. And if the community really can't decide - a mod can always arbitrate if necessary. The only real thing that would be untoward and would get a mod's attention very quickly is if someone went around dupe hammering a significant amount of questions to their own...

Comment: To jump in here, i was the one who reversed it in the first place, following this discussion in the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941163/polymorph-ability-of-virtual-function-called-in-destructor-of-base-class).  The feeling was that the highly upvoted answer was in fact misleading at best (and more likely wrong), and thus the later question should be where the dupe edge resolves to.  If there were a way to merge, I'd have done that instead